# Does an application installed with sudo have root privileges?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, package-management

I tried to use `dpkg` to install an application, but it reminded me I need to execute it via `sudo`.

I don't know if the program now has root privileges when running.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo dpkg ...` will run `dpkg` with root privileges. This is required to perform the installation, e.g. for writing files in system directories. It does not make the program you are installing run with root privileges later, **but** the installation package may install programs in a way that a program in this software package will automatically run as root later, as deemed necessary by the author or maintainer. This is defined in the package.

In this regard you have to trust the author or package maintainer unless you have sufficient expertise to check the contents of the package prior to installing.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic but formally speaking, *running sudo whatever* does **not** give root priviledges to whatever. It does give root priviledges **to the user** running *whatever*.

Answer (score 0):

When the program runs, you can do

```
ps -ef
```

possibly followed by a `| grep some_pattern` to limit the output. The first column called `USER` is the user that the program runs under.

If it is a program that is started by a normal user, it is in general running under that user. However, some programs may run under a specific user (generally root) if the SETUID bit is set. You can find these programs with

```
find / -perm /4000 -ls
```

If your program is not there, it runs under the user that started it. Although, if it is started by `root` (f.e. via `systemd` or `cron`), it may change user to a non-root user.